# c# values don't work correctly

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm new to c# and I tried making a simple program. After I click the button, the values won't update with their actual value, so I have to click twice to make them actually work. Here's my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static int p;
        private static int money;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            p = 0;
            money = 100;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m.Text = money.ToString();
            ex.Text = p.ToString();

            if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot select both.", "Nope");
            }
            else if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                p += 2;
            }
            else if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                money -= 50;
                p += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: 1) no need for `static` here. 2) the code that shows the data is missing.

Comment: use double `&&` for logical AND operation. Also see [Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: Since you're a newbie I wonder if you really mean `&` or `&&`.

Comment: @Habib and @silvermind `&` is a valid boolean operator. `&&` is only slightly better here, but this is not the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I know its not a problem, it is just that `&&` would improve readability and looks more like `AND` :). Also `&&` would do the short circuit if possible, but single `&` will not.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, that's why it's a comment `&&` not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update the text after updating the value

```
if (checkBox1.Checked & checkBox2.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You cannot select both.", "Nope");
}
....

 m.Text = money.ToString();
 ex.Text = p.ToString();
```